# can I use PiSBUS with python

Tags: raspberry-pi, sbus

is it possible to use PiSBUS library with python?
I know you can use it programming with Arduino IDE or something similar, but is it possible to use it with a Raspberry Pi and python?

Link to the GitHub repository of PiSBUS:
git clone https://github.com/1arthur1/PiSBUS.git